# Ngb Date Picker disabled specific dates in the calendar Angular

Tags: angular, date, ng-bootstrap

I am using Ngb Date picker for my form. currently  I need to disable some dates in the calendar.
I am using below code. Below function is working well.

```
      disabledDates: NgbDateStruct[] = [{ year: 2021, month: 10, day: 27 }, { year: 2021, month: 10, day: 28 }]

  isDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct, current: { month: number, year: number }) => {
    return this.disabledDates.find(x => new NgbDate(x.year, x.month, x.day).equals(date)) ?
      true : false;
  }
```

[image]

Now I need to set this dynamically. I am using below function to get data

```
      loadHolidayDates(code) {
    console.log(code);
    this.scheduleCheckInService.getHolidays(code).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

this is the current JSON format.
[image]

How i modify my ngb disabled Dates according to current JSON format.
Thanks